# Low FPS in game while not using 100% specs

Tags: performance

I have strange issue. While playing League of Legends I have pretty low FPS, around 80 with some sudden drops. That's strange because my CPU and GPU utilization does not exceed 30 %. I cannot increase it further. I have FPS cap set to 120 FPS. Other games can reach 100% GPU utilization with ease. All drivers up to date. Where can be source of the problem?

SPECS:
Ryzen 7 1700x, PowerColor RX6600, Windows 10, 16 GB Ram, 20GB free on system SSD, LoL installed on another SSD partition.

Comment: What's your monitor's refresh rate?

Comment: 144 Hz, but Vsync is off

Comment: You can't force an application to utilize the GPU more than is required.  LoL required specifications are extremely low.  RX6600 is 1,500% to 2,000% faster then the listed required AMD GPU.  I suspect the slow downs are not due to your GPU.

Comment: sort of left field, but one potential source is anti-cheat. I don't know what LoL uses, but I know that Elden Ring had a strange interaction with easy-anti cheat and certain windows updates that caused the same symptom in the game for a subset of users. Anecdotes are not data, but see for example: https://www.reddit.com/r/Eldenring/comments/t2ht3u/low_fps_fix_nonstuttering_disable_easy_anticheat/

Comment: Unfortunately, my Windows is updated, and my CPU does not match Win 11 min specs which is ridiculus if you ask me... :(